# Joining sequential records in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I've got a database of messages which contain various pieces of information that come in.  One such piece is a state change messages so my table looks like the following.

```
    +-----------+--------------+---------+
    | MessageId | RecievedUTC  |  State  |
    +-----------+--------------+---------+
    |    1      | 1/1/2010 5pm |   Off   |
    +-----------+--------------+---------+
    |    2      | 1/2/2010 8am |   Idle  |
    +-----------+--------------+---------+
    |    3      | 1/2/2010 9am | Working |
    +-----------+--------------+---------+
```

I'd like get a list of records which state how long I was in each state something like for a report and a maybe a pretty bar chart of how time was spent.

```
    +---------+---------------+--------------+
    |  State  |    StartUTC   |    StopUTC   |
    +---------+---------------+--------------+
    |   Off   | 1/1/2010 5pm  | 1/2/2010 8am |
    +---------+---------------+--------------+
    |   Idle  | 1/1/2010 8am  | 1/2/2010 9am |
    +---------+---------------+--------------+
```

etc.  In my mind its no harder than a join of the table with itself, offset by 1 record ordered by the RecievedUTC.

The best TSQL I could come up with is something to the effect of

```
SELECT m1.State, m1.RecievedUTC as StartUTC, MIN(m2.RecievedUTC) as StopUTC
FROM MessageStates as m1
  INNER JOIN MessageStates as m2 ON MessageStates ON m2.RecievedUTC > m1.RecievedUTC
GROUP BY m1.MessageId, m1.State, m1.RecievedUTC
```

Or as a sub query to get StopUTC but both perform horribly with only 30-40k records taking almost 5 minutes to do this join.

If I wrote this in C# I would keep the track of the previous RecievedUTC and state so when I saw the next record I could combine the next RecievedUTC with it and in linear time have the data as I wanted it.

Comment: @MerickOWS: Can you confirm the version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH MsgStates AS 
(
  SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RecievedUTC ) RN
    FROM MessageStates a
)
SELECT a.State, a.RecievedUTC StartUTC, b.RecievedUTC StartUTC
  FROM MsgStates a, MsgStates b
 WHERE a.rn = b.rn+1
```

Comment: @Andriy Using 2008R2 so no problems there, have to wait until monday to test the speed.

Comment: thanks, this performs tons faster.  Results come in <1 sec instead of 5 minutes ;)